# Where is the GeoIPOrg.dat file?

Tags: geoip, freegeoip

I did the following on my Ubuntu
sudo pip install pygeoip

More here: 
https://code.google.com/p/pygeoip/wiki/Usage

On commandline, 
import pygeoip 
works

But what is the actual location of this file?  I tried "find" command but no luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module doesn't come with the database. You have to download it separately (and keep it updated). The [documentation lists some supported databases](http://pygeoip.readthedocs.org/en/v0.3.2/supported-databases.html).